# EPPlus: How to traverse through every content block (cell or merged range) of a worksheet?

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm trying to traverse through cells and merged cells inside a worksheet, and replace some template texts with dynamic values. However, I didn't manage to loop through all non-empty cells until now. Currently I tried this code, but it threw NullReferenceException when it tried to access the Text property of a cell which is merged.

I'm using a template file, copying the template worksheet from there into my constructed workbook. I tried it with a single workbook without the copy, it gave the same result.

I also tried to put the Where(cell => !cell.Merge) closure into the first foreach loop, but with the same result.

```
    using (var p = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(templateFile)))
    {
        var ws = _excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report", p.Workbook.Worksheets[sablonMunkafuzet]);
        foreach (ExcelRangeBase cell in ws.Cells)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text)) continue;
            var s = cell.Text;
            if (s.StartsWith("^^"))
                 ProcessCell(cell, s.Substring(2));
        }
        foreach (string mc in ws.MergedCells)
        {
            var s = ws.Cells[mc].Text;
            if (s.StartsWith("^^"))
                 ProcessCell(ws.Cells[mc], s.Substring(2));
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I would like to achieve that what I would do manually if I open that template in Excel. To find every "block" (I mean individual cells, or merged cell ranges) where a specifix text pattern appears, then process it, and change the value of that "block" to what I calculate.

Comment: You know that a `Cell` is a range and can span across multiple columns or rows? So just because the start of the cell is empty does not mean that the end is empty.

Comment: I know that. I would like to achieve that what I would do manually if I open that template in Excel. To find every "block" (I mean individual cells, or merged cell ranges) where a specifix text pattern appears, then process it, and change the value of that "block" to what I calculate.

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: The line where I try to get cell.Text. I'm about to solve this problem soon, I will post the solution here if I get to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like I've found a solution for my scenario, here it is if anyone needs such code in the future.

The following code piece loops through every block (individual cell or merged range) in a worksheet, and does some processing. In this case I'm doing a text examination if there is any replacable formula for me. The ^^ is my special signal to indicate that there is a template definition inside the block what should be replaced with my runtime data.

```
    var ws = _excel.Workbook.Worksheets["myTemplateWorksheet"];
    var dim = ws.Dimension;
    // first loop through all non-merged cells
    for (int r = dim.Start.Row; r <= dim.End.Row; ++r)
        for (int c = dim.Start.Column; c <= dim.End.Column; ++c)
        {
            if (ws.Cells[r, c].Merge) continue;
            string s = GetRangeText(ws.Cells[r,c]);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) continue;
            if (s.StartsWith("^^"))
                ProcessCell(ws.Cells[r, c], s.Substring(2));
        }
    // then loop through all merged ranges
    foreach (string mc in ws.MergedCells)
    {
        string s = GetRangeText(ws.Cells[mc]);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) continue;
        if (s.StartsWith("^^"))
            ProcessCell(ws.Cells[mc], s.Substring(2));
     }
```

With the helper method, which extracts the text from a range, taking the array representation of merged ranges into count:

```
private string GetRangeText(ExcelRangeBase range)
{
    var val = range.Value;
    string s = val as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        object[,] arr = val as object[,];
        if (arr != null && arr.GetLength(0) > 0 && arr.GetLength(1) > 0)
            s = arr[0, 0] as string;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && val != null)
        s = val.ToString();
    return s;
}
```